# Jupyter notebook error reponsenotready idle error

Tags: python, jupyter

when I want to run the cell in Jupyter notebook I get this error `**"reponsenotready :  idle "**`.
I am new to Jupyter. Please help me with that.Thanks.

Comment: It would help us help you if you said where you are using Jupyter notebook. Local install? Anaconda used for install? What type of system if local? Also is that the exact error? There really isn’t spaces between the words?

Comment: This won't help you if you really need things to work locally, but a suggestion is to use it remotely. It's a nice option if you are trying to explore the Jupyter ecosystem & don't want to be troubled by installing yet. You can use ephemeral instances via MyBinder. For example, go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) & click `launch binder`. Save to local often if you make anything useful as they expire irrevocably if you aren't active for more than 10 minutes & expire after a few hours even if you are. Google Colab & Azure Notebooks are more stable, less anonymous options.

Comment: I use Anaconda and lunch Jupyter : This is the exact code:  '~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in getresponse(self)
  
       if self.__state != _CS_REQ_SENT or self.__response:
              raise ResponseNotReady(self.__state)

     if self.debuglevel > 0:

ResponseNotReady: Idle  '

Comment: I used the same code before and it worked properly but I should add that I made a copy from my notebook file and I think after that something happened. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.The connection request line was deleted accidently. I am new in Jupyter. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out. It sounds like it would have been more of a Python issue if it had been more than a deleted line of code. Jupyter can actually run a lot of languages, such as R, Julia, etc., and so while it is good to say you are running your code in a Jupyter notebook, in the future it will help people better help you to describe better what you are trying to do more and with what type of code when you see the issue And show some of the involved code when you can.